# Create one mpeg-dash segment

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav, mpeg-dash

I have video encoded in mpeg-dash(*.mpd, init segments, video segments)
Task is to replace one of video segments with segment generated by me. And so video is still can be played.

I read properties of one segment(combining init segment and video segment) using

```
avformat_open_input
avformat_find_stream_info
```

1) I have tried to use [dash muxer](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#dash-2) to generate new segment.

```
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&avFormatContext, NULL, "dash", filename)
```

But the problem is it creates mpd manifest, and other segments. So how to force it to create one segment?

2) When I parsed segment I noticed that it had format "QuickTime / MOV".

```
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&avFormatContext, NULL, "mov", filename);
```

So my another idea was to use "mov" encoder. And set properties same as in initial segment(start time, duration, resolution). 
But here the question is how to remove init header? Because I already have init segment.

Are there any other approaches to generate one mpeg-dash segment and how to solve my problems?